# PySpark cannot insertInto Hive table because "Can only write data to relations with a single path"

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have a Hive Orc table with a definition similar to the following definition

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `example.example_table`(
  ...
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'path'='s3a://path/to/table') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3a://path/to/table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  ...
)
```

I am attempting to use PySpark to append a dataframe to this table using "df.write.insertInto("example.example_table")". When running this, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only write data to relations with a single path.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:134)
    ...
```

When looking at the underlying [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSourceStrategy.scala#L187), the condition that throws this error is checking to see if the table location has multiple "rootPaths". Obviously, my table is defined with a single location. What else could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

It is that path that you are defining that causes the error. I just ran into this same problem myself. Hive generates a location path based on the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property, so you have that default location plus the path you specified, which is causing that linked code to fail.

If you want to pick a specific path other than the default, then try using `LOCATION`.

Try running a `describe extended example.example_table` query to see more detailed information on the table. One of the output rows will be a **Detailed Table Information** which contains a bunch of useful information:

```
Table(
  tableName:
  dbName:
  owner:
  createTime:1548335003
  lastAccessTime:0
  retention:0
  sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:
    location:[*path_to_table*]
    inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
    outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
    compressed:false
    numBuckets:-1
    serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(
      name:null
      serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
      parameters:{
        serialization.format=1
        path=[*path_to_table*]
      }
    )
    bucketCols:[]
    sortCols:[]
    parameters:{}
    skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[]
    skewedColValues:[]
    skewedColValueLocationMaps:{})
    storedAsSubDirectories:false
  )
  partitionKeys:[]
  parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1548335003}
  viewOriginalText:null
  viewExpandedText:null
  tableType:MANAGED_TABLE
  rewriteEnabled:false
)
```

Comment: In my case, the "location" and "path" values of the "describe extended" query match and are what I was expecting. I am using an external table as well.

Comment: Mine also matched, but I think that is the problem, that Spark is seeing both of them. Since the location is automatically generated, you don't need to specify the path manually.

Comment: Hi @conrosebraugh Any Luck on this one, Did you overcome this Problem?

Comment: @Pavan_Obj unfortunately I did not find a work around. I think I ended up using Hive for the class of tables that had this issue so that I could move on to other projects. I should've opened a bug with the Apache Spark team.

Comment: I am glad that you responded, Conroe :)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in a project when migrating from Spark 1.x and HDFS to Spark 3.x and S3. We solve this issue **setting the next Spark property to false**:

```py
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet
```

You can just run

```py
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false")
```

Or maybe

```py
spark.conf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", False)
```

Being spark the SparkSession object. The explanaition of this is currently in [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion).